# Join slowed by WHERE condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, indexing, database-performance

One of our views, which ordinarily is pretty quick, is taking ages to run since midday yesterday. Nothing has been changed, but it is now taking minutes to run.

```
SELECT 
    T1.ITEMNO,
    ROUND(SUM(T3.TOTAL * V1.USDCOST), 3) USDTOTALCOST,
    ROUND(SUM(T3.TOTAL * V1.GBPCOST), 3) GBPTOTALCOST,
    SUM(T3.TOTAL) AS TOTALCOMPONENTS
FROM
    TABLE1 T1 WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 WITH (NOLOCK) ON T1.RECORD_ID = T2.RECORD_ID
    INNER JOIN TABLE3 T3 WITH (NOLOCK) ON T1.RECORD_ID = T3.RECORD_ID AND T2.LINENO = T3.LINENO
    INNER JOIN VIEW1 V1 ON T2.COMPONENTNO = V1.ITEMNO
WHERE
    T2.COMPONENTNO <> '' AND T1.WINDOW_ID = 'COMPONENTS'
GROUP BY T1.ITEMNO
```

Now, if I remove the calculated `USDTOTALCOST` and `GBPTOTALCOST` columns, then the query runs really quickly. Separately, if I remove the condition `T1.WINDOW_ID = 'COMPONENTS'` then that also vastly increases the speed of the query.

`VIEW1` runs really quickly on its own as well, it just seems to cause this view to slow down when it is joined and the `T1.WINDOW_ID = 'COMPONENTS'` condition isn't imposed.

I am stuck - I no longer know where to check to try and get this query running in a reasonable amount of time. I would ordinarily check which indexes SSMS recommends I create at the top of the execution plan, but there are no such suggestions when I check the execution plan for this query.

What could have caused the query to slow down so much? What can I do to try and get this working again?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may need to create some indexes...rerun your query with "Include Actual Execution Plan" option selected and see where it "suffers"

Comment: You must have commented before I edited the question :). I have run the execution plan but there are no suggestions for new indexes.

Comment: How many rows are there in total? You might have reached your server's memory limit - it might be swapping to disk, hence the performance problems (and the fact that seemingly any change extremely affects performance).

Comment: The query only returns 6263 rows, and we have 64GB of memory on the sql server

Comment: You need an index on T1.WINDOW_ID (for filtering without a full table scan) and on T2.RECORD_ID, T3.LINENO and V1.ITEMNO, (for finding the few relevant records across joins without a full table scan).

Comment: Tried adding those to no avail, the query is just as slow as before

Comment: It's not just about how many records the query returns - how many are there in total?

Comment: Have you explicitly recompiled the view and the query?

Comment: in fact you should,set recompile on above query and test for every parameter.it may not be optimize but it will work

Comment: Can you share the SQL command of VIEW1 ?. Also a picture of your Execution Plan would be useful to see the bottlenecks.

Comment: @MarcGuillot what would be the best way to get an image of the execution plan? The text is small as I have to zoomout.

Comment: paste it as xml ,see here on ,how to get an execution plan:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan

Comment: @MihaiOvidiuDrăgoi SSMS is only using 30% of the server memory at the moment, I don't think it's a memory issue

Comment: @KumarHarsh I have recompiled the view and it is still slow, what do you mean by "test for every parameter"?

Comment: By the way, try adding: with option(recompile) at the end of you query. This will force to discard any saved plan and recompile it.

Comment: @TheGameiswar you want me to paste all the XML in here?

Comment: @Sinfieldd: you can paste here :https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: No need - I managed to sort with an index on a table that was being queried against in VIEW1. Thanks for the assistance anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to resolve this by following the execution plan and seeing that there was a `Hash Match` taking 20% and an `Index Scan` taking 14%.

[image]

I created an index on the table that was being scanned for an index and the query immediate sped up.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IND_POPRECORD ON POP30310(PORCTNM)
```

Comment: "following the execution plan", which software did you use for creating that diagram and how did you calculate the percentages?

Comment: "following the execution plan", which software did you use for creating that diagram and how did you calculate the percentages?

Comment: That's the execution plan generated by SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Answer (score 0):

1. If it possible create an index on view and use with(noexpand) hint in query. This will improve your view performance.
2. Create a filter index on Table1 with T1.WINDOW_ID = 'COMPONENTS'